# What layout is required for Japanese ASB-KY4 compressed keyboard?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I got a Japanese compressed ASB-KY4 keyboard while I was over in Japan (so I could use it for entering Japanese text).

[image: ASB-KY4 compressed keyboard]

However, none of the keyboard layouts I configure it with match up properly. The 'c', 'd', and 'e' keys aren't recognised (`xev` and `showkey` show nothing).

And of course, the [manual](http://www.acrosjp.com/USB-KEY2/ky4torisetu.jpg) is in Japanese, and it doesn't look like it gives any indication of the number of keys (which would help me identify an appropriate layout).

Comment: Unfortunately the manual says nothing about setting the keyboard layout. Can you try it on another OS system?

Comment: Are you sure the keyboard is OK? It is strange that C, D, E all in a row don't work. xev should show any key press.

Comment: I will have to check a computer with VIsta or lower, as the Installation driver does not support any higher :( I will see if I can find an old laptop.

Comment: @user3169, would looking at the driver files yield anything useful?

Comment: I guess you mean there was no driver supplied for Ubuntu, right? But I think you don't need any driver just to check key presses, as long as the system detects the keyboard. If the keys work but the correct characters are not displayed, then you need a driver.

Answer (score 0):

As far I can tell, the issue with 'c', 'd', 'e' (and the '3' as I had found) keys is a hardware problem. Either something stuck on the membrane, a connection issue to the board, or membrane damage. I haven't confirmed yet because the screw holding it together are 'triangle' screws - I can't find any bit to unfasten them.

For the layout, I found that to be able to input do romaji and kana input, all I needed to do was change the keyboard layout in the Ibus Anthy preferences under the 'Typing Method' tab:

[image: Ibus Anthy Keyboard Layout preferences]

This was originally set to Default (US keyboard). Once set to 'jp' it reads most of the keys correctly and properly reads the characters when doing kana input.